# Is there a significant difference between echoing code directly inside a php file vs from an objects method?

Tags: php

Is there a significant difference worth worrying about with regard to speed when doing the following?

**Directly in php code**

```
echo "<div>This is a large string in a div</div>";
```

**Calling method from class with the same string**

```
$method = new Methods();    
echo $method->getString();
```

**Class that has function**

```
class Methods
        {
            public function getString()
            {
                return "<div>This is a large string in a div</div>"; 
            }

        }
```

Comment: No.. its just an example, the class has much more that I will be using.

Comment: i don't think there is a major difference. But in terms of speed, `echo` should be faster as no class is initialized and all. BUt its really minor

Comment: your output will be faster if you will use `echo '<div>This is a large string in a div</div>';`